# Failed to load .gemrc

Tags: rubygems

Trying to update my gems and keep running into the error 'Failed to load .gemrc' with no explanation. Any help?

[image: failed .gemrc error from CPU]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try verify the spaces in the file.

Must be:

```
gemhome: /home/user/.gems
gempath:
- $HOME/.gems
```